# Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException weblogic server 12.2.1

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-security, weblogic12c

I am new to spring ,spring security,and weblogic so i am developing a project that is using them.
i am using here weblogic server 12.2.1 
however the problem is the project is working perfect on tomcat 8 server 
and i have deployed the application once on weblogic and it is worked once before i added spring security ,but after i have finished on tomcat now weblogic is asking for a deleted class

my stack trace is

```
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:13 PM AST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application C:\MarsWorkspace\xxx\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is org.xxx.services.Login> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:13 PM AST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1477051442040128" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:196)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:13 PM AST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating distribute task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:13 PM AST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:196)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:17 PM AST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application C:\MarsWorkspace\xxx\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is org.xxx.services.Login> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:17 PM AST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1477056982276446" for task "1" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:196)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:18 PM AST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating distribute task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<Nov 18, 2016 7:15:18 PM AST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:196)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xxx.services.Login
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

now when put this class back i got

```
Error creating bean with name 'login': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

versions in pom.xml

```
<!-- Generic properties -->
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

<!-- Spring -->
<spring-framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
<!-- <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version> -->

<!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
<hibernate.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>

<!-- JSF Version -->
<jsf.version>2.2.13</jsf.version>

<!-- Logging -->
<logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
<slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
 <!-- spring security -->
 <springSecurity.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>
```

also when i have searched for this error i thought maybe the weblogic spring module is conflicting with mine so i have added weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

also i have deleted the cache,log and tmp files in C:\Weblogic12_2_1\user_projects\domains\adminDomain\servers\AdminServer  but nothing happened.

will i was searching for days now but no luck if any body can point me to something it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by lowering the libraries versions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What library version did you lower? Please explain more.

Comment: can you give more details please?